# How do search engines evaluate the usefulness of their results?

Tags: algorithm, search-engine, information-retrieval

A search engine returns 2 results A and B for search "play game XYZ".
People who click on result B spend a much longer time and play a lot more XYZ games at site B, while clickers to site A leave the site after a short visit.

I'd imagine site B is a better search result than site A even though it's possible that site B is new and has few links to it in comparison with A. I assume better search engines would take this into account.

My question is, if so, how do they keep track of usage pattern of a search result in the real world?

Comment: Where did you get this statistic?

Comment: Search engines get results with algorithms [like PageRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank), which sort websites in it's database by how many sites link to it. As more sites like to it, it's reputation is assumed to raise, thus it's ranking. I don't understand why you say that the second result on search engines are always more relevant then the first, as you aren't providing any statistic to back this statement up. I know about this stuff as I run a search engine called [Dumb Search](http://www.dumbsearch.com/).

Comment: RJIGO, it is unlikely for you to find if such tracking exists. I strongly suspect that you found a correlation between these 2 data points, but you analysis why correlation exists is way off (i.e. @amit give much more plausable reason for such correlation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. If a user plays game B a lot - he is likely to write and link about it (blogs, reviews, social networks,....) If he does it, the *static score* of B will raise. This is a part of [**Page Rank algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank), that gives the static score of each page and helps the Search Engine decide which page is better.
2. There is another factor that some Search Engines use: If a user clicked a page, but searched the same/similar query very soon after it - it is likely he did not found what he was after. In this case, the search engine can assume the page is not a good fit ti the query and reduce the score given to this page.

Other then it, the SE cannot really know "how much time you played a game" (unless you revisit it multiple times, by researching the query - and not navigate to it directly, and then it can use the #times the user navigated to the game by searching)

Answer (score 0):

Search engines get results with algorithms [like PageRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank), which sort websites in it's database by how many sites link to it.

From Wikipedia:

> that assigns a numerical weighting to each element of a hyperlinked
>   set of documents, such as the World Wide Web, with the purpose of
>   "measuring" its relative importance within the set.

As more sites like to it, it's reputation is assumed to raise, thus it's ranking.

Other methods can be used as well, like search engines **can** also detect how much time spent on a website, through there external services. Like Google tracks time spent through their widely used tracking/web stat service [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).

As the other answers mention, another method is detecting a site's relevance to the query is if a similar search is conducted within a short time-frame from the previous. This can indicate if the user actually found what they were looking for on the previous site.